# Is There any services in AWS to do CI process for Ms SQL server database in AWS

Tags: devops

I am Stuck with the Process of CI for Database(Ms SQLServer),i am using AWS Devops Services(Code commit,build,deploy) to do CI|CD process of our projects,i have successfully done that on AZURE platform but when i trying to follow the same in the AWS platform i can able to achieve the CI process for the Front-end and Middle ware but when it comes to the Database part i can't able to achieve that,please someone give the best case to achieve the CI process of Database.

Comment: Hi, could you include some code sample and exact error or issue that you are getting. Without that your question is to vague to answer.

Comment: Error::Project "C:\codebuild\tmp\output\src196719351\src\SampleDB\SampleDB.sqlproj" on node 1 (default targets).
C:\codebuild\tmp\output\src196719351\src\SampleDB\SampleDB.sqlproj(58,57): error MSB4226: The imported project "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\BuildTools\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v11.0\SSDT\Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.SqlTasks.targets" was not found. Also, tried to find "Microsoft\VisualStudio\v11.0\SSDT\Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.SqlTasks.targets" in the fallback search path(s) for $(MSBuildExtensionsPath) - "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild" .

Comment: @taleodor attached my error..